# Is humanity truly doomed?

Tags: story, visual, geography

**The aliens have landed!**

You wake up one morning and find yourself in a room with familiar furniture but featureless white walls, strapped firmly to your own bed and hooked up to an array of dials and monitors that are clearly not of human origin. It seems as though your entire bedroom has been snatched away into a spaceship where these extraterrestrials can examine you in order to learn about humans.

Fortunately - whether by oversight or by design, you're not sure - they've left your arms reasonably free to move about and your smartphone within reach of your bed. You grab it and try to access the internet, in the hope of finding out if you're just a lone victim or if this is part of a large-scale invasion. Somehow your device manages to connect to the internet - do aliens have wifi? - but every webpage you try, from countries all over the world, gives you nothing but the same two images:

[image: Europe]
[image: World]

**What information can you gain from these pictures? How widespread is the alien incursion?**

---

<sub>Out-of-character notes for solvers:</sub>

- You can click on each image to see a full-resolution version. Apologies for the graininess.
- The URL superimposed on the upper image is **not a clue** - it just means I swiped these images from http://www.freeworldmaps.net before making my own alterations to them.

Comment: Seal Team Six .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The countries are:

1. Dominican Republic
2. Norway
3. Turkey
4. Spain
5. Iceland
6. Tonga
7. Serbia
8. Turkey
9. Uganda
10. Greenland
11. Estonia
12. Argentina
13. Thailand
14. Iceland
15. Norway
16. Macau
17. Reunion

We can get a message by

> reading the two-letter ISO country codes for each country, which spell out "DO NOT RESIST OR STRUGGLE: EARTH IS NO MORE".

Comment: Too easy!!!!!!!

Comment: So they provide an open access point and serve up those images. Why would I believe this? TIME TO RESIST AND/OR STRUGGLE!

Comment: By the looks of it creating this puzzle took longer than solving it...

Comment: @tuvokki I doubt that is uncommon

Comment: @tuvokki [Definitely](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=34001898#34001898)!